# Center Hamburger, Text and Remove Outline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap, and I'd like to:

1. Center the hamburger in the navbar
2. Remove the boxed outline around the hamburger

[image: navbar]

Current hamburger:

[image: current hamburger]

Here's my code. I've tried a few solutions from here as well, but it still isn't working.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navMenu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="navtext" href="#">TEST 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtext" href="#">TEST 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtext" href="#">TEST 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="navtext" href="#">TEST 4</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

```css
html {
 background-color: black;
}
.navbar {
 background-color: black;
 color: black;
 margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
.icon-bar {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
button {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 outline: none;
 border:0px;
}
.navbar-header{
 background-color: black;
 color: black;
 border: 0px;
}
.navbar-inverse {
 background-color: black;
 color: black;
}
#navMenu {
 color: black;
 background-color: black;
}
.container-fluid {
 color: black;
 background-color: black;
}
li {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;

}
.navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  float: none;
  margin-right:0;
}
a.navtext {
    color: #ffffff;
 border: 3px solid #000000;
 width: 100px auto;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: relative;
}
a.navtext:hover {
    border: 3px solid #F22613!important;
    background: #F22613!important;
}
a.navtext:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
a.navtext:hover:before {
 visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
ul.nav {
 text-align: center!important;
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7. I've also got the centered text issue solved with

```css
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Still have to center the hamburger in the nav and (optionally) get rid of the outline around it. Still lookin for help <3

I've tried switching to 3.0.0, but everything gets screwed up :(

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap V3.3.7

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you're missing is a text-center on your navbar-header.

```
 <div class="navbar-header text-center">
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/35996/)

*It looks like the border around the hamburger is already gone with your CSS*

---

### ---- Update ----

This is how it looks on mine?
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/35997/

Image of text centered:

[image]

Comment: Theres a thin light grey border around the hamburger still. Also, the text-center did not work.

Comment: Have you seen my fiddle? Isn't it working there? And i can't see the grey line in my Fiddle. That means you have some other CSS maybe or another BOOTSTRAP version ?

Comment: In the fiddle, the text is still not centered: https://imgur.com/a/GQtEZ
I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7, perhaps I will switch to 3.0

Comment: I've updated - is there something i'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Different browser maybe?

Comment: The text in the dropdown is fine; its the text in the navbar (before the hamburger appears on screen) that isn't being centered. Should I be using the bootstrap.min.css or the bootstrap-theme.min.css (I've been using the one without the theme)? Also, I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: But that text isn't included in your code? 
Can you include it in your html code, then i will take a look again.

Comment: I've fixed the centering, thanks. (BTW, the text was within the UL element, which acted as a dropdown menu on mobile and appeared as a horizontal bar on wider screens, the latter was the one that I had difficulty centering). Now it's just the hamburger centering and the outline.